# Error resolving Path Alias when Dockerizing NextJS 13 App

Tags: docker, next.js

I created a brand new NextJS app using `npx create-next-app@latest` and I'm trying to build a Docker image from it, and it is failing to resolve my path aliases during the build step. The build step works on my local machine, it just doesn't work when I try to build it into a docker image.

Error Message:

```
#14 3.497 info  - Creating an optimized production build...
#14 5.828 Failed to compile.
#14 5.828
#14 5.828 ./pages/_app.tsx
#14 5.828 Module not found: Can't resolve '@src/styles/globals.css'
#14 5.828
#14 5.828 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
#14 5.828
#14 5.828 ./pages/index.tsx
#14 5.828 Module not found: Can't resolve '@src/styles/Home.module.css'
#14 5.828
#14 5.828 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
#14 5.828
#14 5.829
#14 5.830 > Build failed because of webpack errors
```

Here's a GitHub repo you can clone and try yourself:
https://github.com/TJBlackman/nextjs-docker-test

- `npm run build` works!
- `npm run build:docker` does not work...

Here's the Dockerfile from the repo:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json to the container
COPY package.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY next.config.js .
COPY next-env.d.ts .
COPY src .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Build the Next.js app
RUN npm run build

# Set the environment variable for running the app
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Expose port 3000 for the app to listen on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edits:

- I tried update the Dockerfile to use `node` instead of `node:18-alphine`, but no luck.
- I added `"baseUrl": "."` to the tsconfig.json file, but no luck.

Comment: I have the same issue. It works locally, but not in the Docker container. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `COPY src .` to `COPY src/ src/`

Brainfart. It happens to the best of us... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯